# How do I build several .exe with 1 slight change in the code anytime?

Tags: vb6

The thing is I need to make 8000 files, the same VB6 project, but there is just ONE variable that needs to change it's number in each file. I'll spend a lot of hours building files manually.

I've tried using a .txt as a variable source, so I've created another project which changes the .txt number and compile the original project with "vb6.exe /make" in command line, while in the original project I made it read the .txt to get the number. BUT... It takes the whole reading the file code and when executed the .exe it tries to find the .txt instead of showing the value of it adquired while the build. Dah!

Any chances of building an .exe file from VB6 textbox.text code?

For example:

Textbox1.Text = "MsgBox ("hello")"

And then build an .exe from Textbox1.Text, so it will open a msgbox saying "hello"

---

I've done it by editing the .frm file (well, you can't edit, but you can create a new one), here are some code you'll find useful if you're trying to do batch compile codes with programmatical changes something similar:

'Editing .frm file

```
Open "C:\Form1.frm" For Output As #1
Print #1, Label1.Caption & vbCrLf & Label2.Caption & Text1.Text & Label3.Caption 'Here goes the entire .frm code, the changes are in Text1.Text
Close #1
```

'Shell Compiler

```
Shell (VB6path & " /make " & ProjectPath & " /outdir " & EXEPath)
```

'Copy the file with the needed name

```
FileCopy ("C:\Project1.exe"), ("C:\" & Text1.Text & ".exe") 'Text1.Text contains the rotating name.
```

'Delete Project1.exe

```
If Dir("C:\Project1.exe") <> "" Then
Kill "C:\Project1.exe"
End If
```

You can make an array or take the variable data to insert in the .frm file from another file with a list, or whatever.

Comment: Some function like this would be amazing:

BuildExeFromCode(Textbox1.Text), "C:\msgbox.exe"

Or any other kind of solution to make the same project several files, but changing a variable number each time.

Comment: it is possible to build an vb6 project in a batch file (you would have to search the calling syntax. then you would need a small program reading the vbp file (changing output exe name) and in your source you need some kind of placeholder, and a small program to replace the placeholder with your desired value.

Comment: @deblocker , if I could make an .exe file from the content of Textbox1.Text I could replace by code the "hello" every time before launching the "BuildExeFromCode(Textbox1.Text)". The thing is the text is not a simple "hello", it is an ID which will look something like 1_red_small, 1_red_medium, 1_red_large, and like that 28 combinations per each number, then, starts with 2, 3, 4... I'm trying to make 28 exe file combinations at once, for 1, then for 2, then, for 3.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Yes, I know that, I've actually already done something similar, not using a batch file, but Shell() in VB6, which is pretty the same., but I can't find any way to replace a variable value from a list before building the next file.

Comment: Maybe I should use AutoIT and make a bot, but I was trying to find a better and permanent way to do it from VB6.

Comment: The only reference I can think about to explain better my situation (even while it is not my objective at all) is this: Think about a RAT or trojan builder, which creates .exe files from some options the user set before building the exe files. How do I do that?

Comment: vb6 source files are plain ascii - you must read the file and replace the string in your source file, and write back (I would use a "template" file with a unique placeholder for easy replace)

Comment: @sisorken: ok, thank you, i believe i got it now. On PlanetSourceCode you will find a "Batch VB Compiler". The rest is a matter of read and write text files, as nabuchodonossor already pointed out.

Comment: OMG, I've never realized the .frm files are ASCII, you saved me a lot of hours of boring work! Thank you so much! I imagine this will work fine in VB.NET projects as well, using msbuild.exe instead of vb6.exe

Comment: @sisorken: you should change the.Project file (vbp) and IMHO you should use a module (.bas) to store the variables you need to change.

Comment: I've just edited the .frm and made the whole batch compile, it worked like a charm! Please check the updated info in my question. Thank you all! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I have to ask. Why not read the text file at runtime? So you have 1 exe, 8000 text files?

Comment: You don't have to edit the source. The vb6.exe program supports a command line argument where you can specify compile constants. Run "vb6.exe /?" for info. So you can create an 8000 line batch file, each line of which is one compile, with a compile argument for the unique value and a different output folder/exe name. Then in code, have a humongous #If #ElseIf cascade where you enumerate all of the values to compile in. (But I gotta say that I'd be doing this along the lines of @MarkJ 's comment and have a single exe with a runtime config file of some sort)

Comment: If the project reads a config file to take the variable data it would not work for what I'm doing (that was the first thing I've done and realized it didn't work for my project). Anyway, it's working great.

Comment: You can read the dynamic text from the executable's .res section. Then just produce 8000 .exe files with modified resource strings.